# Calling the static methods of a java/groovy object using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, groovy

I'm working on a groovy unit-testing class that contains a collection of rules for whether or not the contents of a file are correctly formatted. (Not using a proper rules engine, it just takes advantage of Groovy's assertion capabilities to do validation in a way that vaguely resembles what a rules engine would do.) I was thinking that I could create a method called FireAllRules that looks like this:

```
public static void FireAllRules(File file)
{
    for(def method in Class.getMethods)
    {
        if(method.name.indexOf("rule" == 0) method.invoke(file);
    }
}
```

All the methods that I want the loop to pick up on are static, and I noticed during the debugging process none of my rule methods are included in the Class.getMethods() enumeration. Ideally, I would like to only loop over the methods that I personally wrote into the class rather than sorting through dozens of uninteresting methods that come in along with java.Object. Is there a way to use reflection to iterate over these static methods at runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given:

```
class Test {
  public static testThis() {
    println "Called testThis"
  }

  public static woo() {
    println "Called woo"
  }

  public static testOther() {
    println "Called testOther"
  }
}
```

You can do:

```
Test.metaClass.methods.grep { it.static && it.name.startsWith( 'test' ) }.each {
  it.invoke( Test )
}
```

To print:

```
Called testOther
Called testThis
```

A more generic method to execute the static test methods of a class would be:

```
def invokeClass( clazz ) {
  clazz.metaClass.methods.grep { it.static && it.name.startsWith( 'test' ) }.each {
    it.invoke( clazz )
  }
}

invokeClass( Test )
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I had in mind. The only problem I'm running into is that the compiler's complaining that it.invoke(clazz) has the wrong number of arguments. Do you know why that might be? EDIT: Nevermind, I got it.

Comment: @estanford You could try `it.invoke( clazz, null )` oddly the single arg version works for me...  what version of Groovy?  1.8.6?

Comment: @tim_yates I noticed that your example was different from mine insofar as I was passing a File object into all the rules and your example didn't, so I had to call the invoke method as `it.invoke(clazz, file)` in order to make it work properly.

Comment: @estanford ahhh yes...  Sorry, I forgot that originally when I was coming up with the code above :-(  Glad you got it sorted out though! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Static methods are included in the methods returned by `getMethods()`.  Your issue might be `method.name.indexOf("rule" == 0)`.  This should be `method.name.indexOf("rule") == 0`, or better yet `method.name.startsWith("rule")`.

Also, are your rule methods public?  If not, you can use `getDeclaredMethods()`.  To invoke them, you will have to call `setAccessible()` first.

Answer (score 2):

The java version would be something like this (I've removed the imports and exceptions for clarity).

```
public class FindAndRunStaticMethods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fireAllRules();
    }

    public static void fireAllRules() {
        for(Method method : StaticMethodClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            findAndRunRules(method);
        }
    }

    private static void findAndRunRules(Method method) {
        if (!Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers())) return;
        if (!method.getName().startsWith("rule")) return;
        if (!method.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE)) return;

        Class[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();

        if (parameterTypes.length != 1) return;
        if (!parameterTypes[0].equals(File.class)) return;

        method.invoke(null, new File("dummy"));
    }
}
```

A sample test class could look like this

```
public class StaticMethodClass {
    public static void ruleHere(File x) { System.out.println("should print"); }
    public static void ruleRun(File x) { System.out.println("should print"); }  
    public void ruleNotSelected() { System.out.println("not run"); }
}
```